# function return synchronously in Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

In my AngularJS app, I have the following variable:

```
var meals = _.times(mealCount, function(index) {
    return new MealPlanResource({
      dayId:                  dayId,
      userFriendlyMealNumber: index + 1,
      items:                  [],
    });
  });
```

How do I make it so that the next line of the function does not run until the _.times has fully executed?

I have attempted:

```
var mealsDeferred = $q.defer();
var meals = mealsDeferred.resolve(getUpdatedMeals());

function getUpdatedMeals() {
    _.times(mealCount, function(index) {
      return new MealPlanResource({
        dayId:                  dayId,
        userFriendlyMealNumber: index + 1,
        items:                  [],
      });
    });
  }
```

As well as:

```
var meals;
setTimeout(function() {
  _.times(mealCount, function(index) {
      return new MealPlanResource({
        dayId:                  dayId,
        userFriendlyMealNumber: index + 1,
        items:                  [],
      });
    });
}, 100);
```

Both are returning meals as 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `_.times()` function is the one from [LoDash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#times), then your code should work as is.

`_.times()` is a *synchronous* function. It is not asynchronous. It completes all execution before returning a value. You do not need to use promises with it, and they won't do you any good.

Here is a working example of your code:

```js
function MealPlanResource( args ) {
    _.assign( this, args );
}

var mealCount = 3;
var dayId = 1;

var meals = _.times(mealCount, function(index) {
    return new MealPlanResource({
        dayId: dayId,
        userFriendlyMealNumber: index + 1,
        items: [],
    });
});
  
console.log( meals );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Can you compare that with your actual code and perhaps see what is different?

Comment: You are correct.  My problems is elsewhere in the code.  Thank you.